# Django 1.10: Translation/Localization Not Switching Languages (Using Non-Default Language?)

Tags: python, django, translation

I am working on a web-app and I want to be able to switch between specifically English and Filipino (Tagalog) using [Django's i18n functionalities](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#). Right now, my webpage is literally just "hello", but I want it to show the Filipino translation ("Kamusta"), and I tried to implement my view.py such that it happens. However, it still just says "hello", and doesn't switch. Here is what I have so far.

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'example/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('tl', _('Tagalog')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'example/locale'),
)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY
from django.utils import translation

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    translation.activate("tl")
    request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = "tl"
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

index.html:

```
{% load i18n %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  {% trans "Hello world!" %}
</body>

</html>
```

django.po:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-06-06 04:40+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: example/templates/index.html:12
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "Kamusta"

#: translate/settings.py:120
msgid "English"
msgstr ""

#: translate/settings.py:121
msgid "Tagalog"
msgstr ""
```

I've been digging around, and from what I understand, Filipino is not a "default LANGUAGE" that Django recognizes. Does that mean I can't translate at all? Some part of me believes that there's got to be a way. There's so many languages in the world, there's no way Django only supports translations for like 40 of them.